# Multivariate Regression Numpy for Math Homework

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm looking to use multivariate regression with least squares as my cost function to find a,b,c for ax^2 +bx + c that best fits cos(x) from (-2,2). My cost won't decrease but is ridiculously high- what I am doing wrong?

```
x = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
y = np.cos(x)

theta = np.random.random((3,1))
m = len(y)

for i in range(10000):
    #Calculate my y_hat
    y_hat = np.array([(theta[0]*(a**2) + theta[1]*a + theta[2]) for a in x])

    #Calculate my cost based off y_hat and y
    cost = np.sum((y_hat - y) ** 2) * (1/m)

    #Calculate my derivatives based off y_hat and x
    da = (2 / m) * np.sum((y_hat - y) * (x**2))
    db = (2 / m) * np.sum((y_hat - y) * (x))
    dc  = (2 / m) * np.sum((y_hat - y))

    #update step
    theta[0] = theta[0] - 0.0001*(da)
    theta[1] = theta[1] - 0.0001*(db)
    theta[2] = theta[2] - 0.0001*(dc)

    print("Epoch Num: {} Cost: {}".format(i, cost))

print(theta)
```

Comment: You've made a mistake. Perhaps it's with the calculation of `y_hat`? `y_hat.shape` returns `(100, 1)`, whereas `y.shape` returns `(100,)`

Answer (score 0):

You're calculation of `y_hat` is slightly incorrect. It's currently a 2D array of shape `(100,1)`.

This should help. It pulls the "zeroith" element from each of the rows:

```
theta_ = [(theta[0]*(a**2) + theta[1]*a + theta[2]) for a in x]
y_hat = np.array([t[0] for t in theta_])
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the difference between the two. I changed it into a one-D array (100,) but my cost isn't optimized still. I'm not too sure where there error lies.....